# The area of a spherical triangle is one sixth of the surface area of the sphere. What is the sum of the angles of this spherical triangle?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Let's let $A_t$ be the area of the triangle and let $A_s$ be the surface area of the sphere. We know that $A_t=\frac{A_s}{6}$ so we get
sum of angles$=\pi+(4\pi \times \frac{\frac{A_s}{6}}{A_s})$ then the 
sum of angles$=\pi+(\frac{2\pi}{3})$; the $A_s$ gets cancelled
therefore the sum of angles=$\frac{5\pi}{3}$

Checking to make sure if this is valid or to see other approaches if possible.

Comment: Looks good to me. Can't get much simpler than that, I don't think another approach is necessary. I'm curious, though, what name did you learn for the theorem which says that (sum of angles) $= \pi + 4 \pi \frac{A_t}{A_s}$?

Comment: I wasn't given that I found it on wikipedia under the Spherical trigonometry section.

Comment: Okay. For the future, you might want to keep the name "Gauss-Bonnet Theorem" in mind, which is what this formula is a special case of.

Answer (score 0):

The ball can be divided to 6 equal parts vertically. Then the digon is a triangle 60 degree*2+180 degree on sphere. Also the surface of sphere is $2\pi*2+\pi-\pi=4\pi$.